# how to get result value JSON and send result Format JSON

Tags: sql-server, query, sql-server-2017, json-path

I have Query for result JSON but I need result like this:

```
result:[ "B":{1628424359816,35},
         "A":{1628424359816,1},
         "B":{1628424380816,63},
         "A":{1628424380816,1}]
```

My query :

```
          ;WITH CTE AS (         
           SELECT DATETIME,[B],[A], 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datetime) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dateadd(minute,1+(datediff(minute, 0, t.DATETIME)/1 )*1, 0) ORDER BY t.DATETIME) AS RN
        FROM test t        WHERE DATETIME >='2021-05-29' AND DATETIME <='2021-08-30'       ), 
        ctmax as (        select          MIN(DATETIME) AS [FIRST],        Max(DATETIME) as [last],        min(rn) as rown
                  FROM cte          group by RN                )
    SELECT DISTINCT DATEDIFF_BIG(MILLISECOND,'1970-01-01 00:00:00',CTE.DATETIME)  AS  DATETIME,
    CTE.[B] ,
    CTE.[A] 
          
    FROM CTE      
    RIGHT JOIN ctmax [CTE3]  ON  cte.DATETIME=[CTE3].last
     ORDER BY DATETIME  for json path
```

My Result :

```
[{"DATETIME":1628424359816,"B":35,"A":1},{"DATETIME":1628424380816,"B":63,"A":1}]
```

db<>fiddle   [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c772c9a39298746311bab7a093cfefc9)

Comment: The results you need is not valid json.

Comment: sql server version is  2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you asked for is not valid. However, it looks like you may want a pretty similar JSON

```json
{
  "result": [
    {
      "B": [1628424359816, 35]
    },
    {
      "A": [1628424359816, 1]
    },
    {
      "B": [1628424380816, 63]
    },
    {
      "A": [1628424380816, 1]
    }
  ]
}
```

For this, you can unpivot the values, then conditionally add different JSON keys

```sql
;WITH CTE AS (         
    SELECT
      DATETIME,
      [B],
      [A], 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datetime) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dateadd(minute, 1 + (datediff(minute, 0, t.DATETIME) / 1 ) * 1, 0) ORDER BY t.DATETIME) AS RN
    FROM test t
    WHERE DATETIME >='2021-05-29' AND DATETIME <='2021-08-30'
), 
ctmax as (
    select
      MIN(DATETIME) AS [FIRST],
      Max(DATETIME) as [last],
      min(rn) as rown
    FROM cte
    group by RN
)
SELECT
  JSON_QUERY(CASE WHEN ab = 'B' THEN value END) AS B,
  JSON_QUERY(CASE WHEN ab = 'A' THEN value END) AS A
FROM CTE      
RIGHT JOIN ctmax [CTE3] ON cte.DATETIME = [CTE3].last
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
    ('B', CONCAT(N'[', DATEDIFF_BIG(MILLISECOND, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', CTE.DATETIME), N',', CTE.B, N']')),
    ('A', CONCAT(N'[', DATEDIFF_BIG(MILLISECOND, '1970-01-01 00:00:00', CTE.DATETIME), N',', CTE.A, N']'))
) v(ab, value)
for json path, ROOT('result')
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2297b360f4c87ea700678379b7745377)

I must say, most of the query, the CTE and grouping etc seem pointless, but I have not changed that